# How to get a handle of the page url / path in .NET for Facebook?

Tags: c#, .net, facebook

I have to put Facebook code for three distinct pages inside my program (videoWall.aspx, videoWallDetail.aspx, and get-involved.aspx).  In the head I will put the code and change it as I need to using an `if` statement, checking against the page to see which code should be used.

How do I get the page url or path or anything I can use to get a hold of the unique page?

Here is my code:

```
// if(page = videoWall.aspx)
        <meta property="og:title" content="Faces of Metastatic Breast Cancer (MBC) Video Wall" />
        <meta property="og:type" content="cause" />
        <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.facesofmbc.org/images/MBC_Logo.png"/>
        <meta property="og:url" content="http://bit.ly/rkRwzx" />
        <meta property="og:site_name" content="Faces of Metastatic Breast Cancer (MBC)" />
        <meta property="og:description" content="I just viewed the new Faces of Metastatic Breast Cancer (MBC) video wall. For each view, comment or share of the video wall during October, Genentech will donate $1 to MBC initiatives. Watch TODAY!" />
        <meta property="fb:admins" content="653936690"/>
```

Obviously I know the `if` won't work like that, but that is just an example of what i want to do, then repeat for the other two instances.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Page.Request.Url.ToString() will show you the entrie url...

you can use

Page.Request.Url.ToString().Split('?')[0] to see just de page...